# How to use Get on a folder

Tags: bugs, import, packages, documentation, initialization

**Documentation flaw introduced before 9.0 and persisting through V11.0.0**

---

In the documentation for `Get` it says:

> If the file found by `<<name` is a directory, the Wolfram Language will
>   try to load the file init.m in that directory.

So I make a folder called `test` with a single file called `init.m` whose only contents are

```
Print["It works."]
```

In the same directory as the folder `test` I open a notebook and run

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
<<test
```

which returns `Get::noopen: Cannot open test`. (Note that `<<test/init.m` works as expected).

What gives?

**Edit:**
This has been filed as a documentation bug to Wolfram.

Comment: @Kuba But also `Get["test", Path -> {NotebookDirectory[]}]` does not work.  I think it should?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Good point :/

Comment: @Kuba Sorry, I didn't understand that last comment.

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14339/5478)

Comment: related: [64739](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64739/5478)

Comment: @Kuba would you update the status of [(60540)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60540/121) as well?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it seems to be fixed but `General::cdir: Cannot set current directory to PerfLogs.
General::cdir: Cannot set current directory to Recovery.
General::cdir: Cannot set current directory to System Volume Information.
General::stop: Further output of General::cdir will be suppressed during this calculation.` is generated when I call `FileNames["D*", "c:\\"]` :D

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `FileNames["D*", $InstallationDirectory, {2}]` works well though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Shortly:

automatic behavior happens when you use a backtick `` ` ``.

---

I think there are multiple typos in docs for [`Get`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Get.html). I added `Test2` dir and and `Test2\init.m` file to the first path in `$Path`. In my case `Links` dir.

According to `Get` documentation `<<Test2` should get it. It won't but `` <<Test2` ``  will.

Additionally this will work, even without `SetDirectory`:

```
Get["Test`", Path -> {NotebookDirectory[]}]
```

and this will work automatically too:

```
SetDirectory @ NotebookDirectory[];
<< Test`
```

So the difference is in ***`` ` ``***.

#### More accurate in description is [tutorial/FilesForPackages](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FilesForPackages.html):

> #### The typical sequence of files looked for by `` <<name` ``:
>
> - `name.mx` file in `DumpSave` format
> - `name.mx/$SystemID/name.mx` file in `DumpSave` format for your computer system
> - `name.m` file in Wolfram Language source format
> - `name/init.m` initialization file for a particular directory
> - `dir/…` files in other directories specified by `$Path`
>
> <…>
>
> If `name` is a directory, then the Wolfram Language will try to load the initialization file `init.m` in that directory.

**So the point is that automatic behaviour happens when you use a backtick `` ` ``.**

Comment: I think this question should be marked as a documentation bug.  The behavior you illustrate is the one we are all familiar with from `Get` and `Needs`.

Comment: Another case in  `<<name`is: `name/Kernel/init.m`

Comment: @Kuba thanks for getting to the bottom of this...I filed a bug.

Comment: @Kuba: I think Murta just wanted to note that `name/Kernel/init.m` is another file which Mathematica tries to open when you use ```Get["name`"]```. I think that this is the older convention for where Mathematica looks for such a file and it will use that before `name/init.m` if both exist. The answer to "why" is of course pure convention, but I guess it has to do with the fact that WRI wants you to be able to distinguish between `FrontEnd/init.m` and `Kernel/init.m` within your package...

Comment: @AlbertRetey For me convention could be arbitrary if it is clearly stated. I failed to find any ref in docs why `Kernel/init.m` is called first. I knew that but lately I'm trying to understand package mechanisms/developement from basics... but there is no clean description for that in docs as I've stressed in this [complaint comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14339/how-to-work-with-application-project-files-in-wolfram-workbench#comment205505_14351). Maybe we could continue in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20179279#20179279)?

Comment: @Kuba, got the reply from Wolfram, they said someone had already filed it.

Comment: @AlbertRetey yes. This was my point. Tks