# How to use the Autoload directory?

Tags: packages, kernel-startup

According to the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframSystemFileOrganization.html), packages in `$UserBaseDirectory/Autoload` will load automatically on startup.  I placed an `.m` file in this directory and it did not get loaded.  How can I get this to work?

Comment: @Kuba Somehow to me it isn't obvious from that description that the `init.m` file is required.  Normally a package can be loaded with ``<<Pack` `` even without an `init.m` file.  But apparently not from Autoload.

Comment: You should take this topic + [symbols lookup](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43629/5478) + [Get with folders](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75539/5478) + [Autoload subtleties](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110243/5478) and add section "documentation doesn't help either" to your community question about support of packages developement.

Answer (score 14):

In order for a package in `Autoload` to load, it must have the file `Kernel/init.m`.  Thus,

- `Autoload/MyPack.m` will not load.
- `Autoload/MyPack/MyPack.m` will also not load.

Instead, we need to have the following structure:

A package file at `Autoload/MyPack/Mypack.m` and an initialization file for the package at `Autoload/MyPack/Kernel/init.m`, containing the usual `` Get["MyPack`MyPack`"] ``.

This is the standard application structure.  However, in other situations, simple packages can also be contained in a single `.m` file, without needing to have a separate directory and `init.m` for them, so I was surprised that that structure didn't work.

For very small packages which are really just meant to be used as initialization code, we can also use a single file placed at `Autoload/MyPack/init.m`, without `MyPack/MyPack.m` or `MyPack/Kernel/init.m`.  This file could be loaded manually by `` <<MyPack` ``.

This is documented in the most clear way (to me) here in [Wolfram System Sessions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframSystemSessions.html#9923), which I found through [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110243/12).

> On startup, the Wolfram Language kernel does the following:
>
> ...
>
> - Loads `init.m` and `Kernel/init.m` files in Autoload directories.

**Notes:**

- Autoload packages are loaded even when using the `-noinit` kernel command line option.  This makes them different from `$UserBaseDirectory/Kernel/init.m`, which isn't loaded with `-noinit`.

**Related:**

- [Handling Kernel start. What is a full initialization stack and what place the Autoload has there?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110243/12)

Comment: One can also argue that "Kernel/init.m files in Autoload directories" can be interpreted as `$Installation | $UserBase | $Base / Autoload / Kernel / init.m` rather than `Autoload / _ / Kernel / init.m`. Maybe it's obvious but only if you know it is... When I was learning things from docs I always wondered if strange wording has a purpose or is a result of lack of time of an author.