# How to make the variables in $init.m$ not impact the autocompletion

Tags: system, system-variables

The autocompletion is very convient in `Mathematica`,but it will make one annoying sometimes when you have a ton variables.I give a scene I encounter.I usually make many custom functions in my `init.m`,for example

```
System`testFunction[variablea_]:=Module[{variableb=variablea},variableb+1]
```

http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-06-25-01-06-52.png

But when I launch my `Mathematica` as soon as there are many variables prompt to auto-autocomplete.like this
[image]

So my question is how to make the variables in `init.m` not impact the autocompletion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't put symbols you don't want to show up in auto-completion into the `` Global` `` context.  Use the same mechanism you would for a package.

```
myfun; (* create in Global` *)
Begin["MyPrivateInitContext`"]
myfun[x_] := Module[{y=x^2}, y^2]
End[]
```

I noticed you are putting your function into the `` System` `` context.  This seems like a bad idea.  The `` System` `` context is for builtins.

---

What I do personally is that I create a complete package and load it with `Needs` in `init.m`.  This way the package lives in its own separate context, i.e. neither in System or Global.

If the package is very simple, it can also be inlines in `init.m`:  just put the same code that would go in the package file into `init.m`

If these definitions need to be accessible from subkernels (when parallelizing), then [use the Autoload directory](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114958/12) instead of `init.m`.

Comment: Upvote.The ``System` `` can prevent my custom function losing its definition from ``Clear["`*"]``

Comment: @yode So can any other context.  ``Clear["`*"]`` only clears ``Global` ``

Comment: You save me again.

Comment: @Szabolcs But lower case functions are sometimes useful in the System` context: you can use them in other packages without trouble. Withy your Global\`myfun you will have to use the longname explicitly in any package. So why not `Begin["MyPrivateInitContext\`"];
System\`testFunction[variablea_] := 
  Module[{variableb = variablea}, variableb + 1];
End[];` ?

Comment: @Rolf Actually I am not advocating using Global.  I think the right way is to use a custom context.  If we want to use this in packages, we can always add it to the `$ContextPath` with one line after `BeginPackage`.  Even better, just put the definitions in a proper package and load the package in `init.m`.   Inside another package, load it with `Needs` or `BeginPackage`. What I do personally is that I put the definitions in a package and put the package in `Autoload`.  This way I can also use it from subkernels when parallelizing.