# Autoload a package

Tags: packages, kernel, kernel-startup

I want to aoutoload a package at the beginning of a notebook.
I set up my directory as written here

[How to use the Autoload directory?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114957/how-to-use-the-autoload-directory/114958#114958)

So, I have these files:

> ../Work/MyFile.nb
>
> ../Work/Autoload/MyPack/MyPack.m
>
> ../Work/Autoload/MyPack/Kernel/init.m.

*MyPack.m* :

```
ClearAll["Progetto`*"];  

BeginPackage[ "Progetto`"]

    Prova::usage="Prova[]"

    Begin["`Private`"];

        Prova[]:=5+1;

    End[]

EndPackage[]
```

*init.m*:

```
 Get["MyPack`MyPack`"]
```

In MyFile.nb, I would like use `Prova[]`, but the output isn't `6` but is `Prova[]`.

Where am I wrong? Am I missing something in `init.m`?

Comment: Is ``Progetto` `` in `$Packages` after kernel launch? And in `$ContextPath`?

Comment: @Kuba Progetto isn't a file. Should I rename "Progetto" in "MyPack"?

Comment: I thought that "Progetto" was the name of the Package

Comment: `$Packages`  contains context that were exported so if `MyPack` was loaded then ``Progetto` `` should be there.

Comment: @Kuba no, in $Packages  there isn't Progetto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to aoutoload a package **at the beginning of a notebook**.

In this case, create an [initialization cell](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InitializationCell.html) in the notebook, and load that package in that cell. Select the cell, and tick Cell menu -> Cell Properties -> Initialization Cell.

"Autoloading" refers to loading something on kernel startup, and is completely independent of notebooks.  This is not what you need.

> So, I have these files:
>
> > ../Work/MyFile.nb
> >
> > ../Work/Autoload/MyPack/MyPack.m

The `Autoload` directory I wrote about in the answer you are linking to is located in `$UserBaseDirectory`.  There is only one* such directory, and it is used on kernel startup.  It does not interact with notebooks in any way.

<sup>* To be completely accurate, there are a few, but they all live in fixed locations, such as `$UserBaseDirectory`, `$BaseDirectory`, `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles`, etc.</sup>