# Why doesn't my package load automatically when placed in \$UserBaseDirectory\Autoload?

Tags: packages, configuration

I'm using Mathematica 10.4 on Windows 10.

I created a package which loads when I run

```
Needs["sub`package`"]
```

That works whether the package is placed relative to the current directory, or in \$UserBaseDirectory\Autoload or $UserBaseDirectory\Applications.

I want it to load when I start Mathematica.  The product documentation strongly suggests that a package placed in \$UserBaseDirectory\Autoload should load when Mathematica starts.  The doesn't happen.

Is there something else I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Does it have Kernel/init.m? [How to use the Autoload directory?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114957/5478)