# How to autoload user-def functions (in a .m or .nb file)?

Tags: packages, autoload

How to autoload a few user-def funcions?.

For example the function

```
emo[x_]:=Module[{a=x},If[x>0,"Happy","Sad"]]
```

saved in a .nb file or in a .m file

I tried creating in
"c:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.3\SystemFiles\Autoload"
a dir MyFuncs and a subdir MyFuncs/Kernel with init.m whose content is

```
Get["MyFunc`MyFunc`"]
```

Another test was

```
$Path=Join[$Path, {"e:\Users\......\Files\Mathematica11_3"}];
```

and then

```
<<MyFunc
<<MyFunc.nb
<<MyFunc.m
```

I´d like to load a fes user defined functions in an easy and practical way, whitout lot of complications. If it were possible from the files dir.

I was reading a lot of posts but whitout success

Comment: Try using init.m (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/init.m.html)

Comment: Also, do not modify anything inside of the installation directory.

Comment: You should run your definitions and save them after into the .mx file by `DumpSave["file.mx"]`. After this, it can be loaded easily by `Get`.

Comment: @RolfMertig I tried with init.m in several ways, It was not helpful.

Comment: It should work. Where did you put MyFunc.m ?

Comment: See also here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114957/12

Answer (score 3):

I also found this not to be straightforward. This is the protocol I eventually adopted;

1. Put your functions in a package e.g. `myStuff.m`.

`` BeginPackage["myStuff`] ``

`(*functions to be exported go here*)`

`myFunc1::usage="explain how to use your function here if you wish"`

`myFunc2::usage="or this can be empty quotes"`

`` Begin["`Private`"] ``

`(*function definitions, including any private functions go here*)`

`myFunc1[x_] := Module[{a=0}, If[x>a, Happy, Sad]];`

`myFunc2[x_] := myPrivateFunc1@x + 1;`

`myPrivateFunc1[x_] := x^2;`

`End[]`

`EndPackage[]`

2. You now need to add the path to `myStuff.m` in a *persistent* manner.

   `$Path = Join[$Path,{"C:\\dir1\\dirWhichHasMyStuff"}]`

   `InitializationValue[$Path] = $Path`
3. If you use `` <<myStuff` ``  now, it should work. However, if you want it to be autoloaded, you need to add it as an initialization context.

   `` InitializationValue[$InitializationContexts] = {"myStuff`"} ``

(Obviously, if you already have other pre-existing initialization contexts, just add it to the existing list otherwise the old ones will be overwritten.)

The package will automatically be loaded next time you start a kernel.

Comment: Thank you. It works. But now I want to go back to the past. I deleted the package, now whenever I open Mathematica, it gives an error about the deleted package. How to achieve package to be non-autoloaded again.

Comment: You need to remove the package from the list of initialization contexts.
If you have no other packages you want to autoload, just do;

`InitializationValue[$InitializationContexts] = {}`

Otherwise just list the packages that you DO want to be autoloaded.