# How to get remote access using a .m file?

Tags: remote-access

I'm trying to use a .m file to remotely connect to a computer in my office and use its six processors in addition to the two on my laptop when running code. The code from the .m file works fine if copy-pasted into my main file, but doesn't work as a .m file using the Get[] command. Can this code just not be put in a .m, or is my implementation bad?

Here's the code (with my lab computer's address removed):

```
Get["tunnel.m"];
Needs["SubKernels`RemoteKernels`"];
kernels = 
  RemoteMachineTunnel["username@servername.net", 6, 
   "OperatingSystem" -> "Unix", 
   "KernelPath" -> "/home/username/Mathematica/MathKernel"];
CloseKernels[];
LaunchKernels[2]; LaunchKernels[kernels];
```

Note that I created the folder "Mathematica" on the lab computer such that this works. I also set up a public key (rather my friend did) so that the tunnel command goes through without being password denied.

Also note that I work at a university with strict restrictions on computer-computer communications, so the built in Wolfram remote access functionality doesn't work for me.

A similar question was asked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64739/how-to-load-a-custom-mathematica-package-from-a-m-file#) but that method does not seem to work here.

I think there's one or two other stackexchange questions I should give credit to for the above code, but my friend wrote it so I have no idea which questions he drew inspiration from.